# How to access Securus DVR camera Live Feeds from my python application

Tags: python, c++, camera, live-streaming, rtsp-client

How can we programmatically access live camera feed from Securus DVR systems into my  application for real-time monitoring?

Are there any available APIs or SDKs to access the Securus system and retrieve live camera data in our application?